# AltBeacon:How to find list of beacons using RegionBootstrap and RangeNotifier

Tags: android, altbeacon

I want my application to scan for beacons in background and if they match with my beacons it open a dialog.
So I have this class

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.powersave.BackgroundPowerSaver;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.RegionBootstrap;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.BootstrapNotifier;

import java.util.Collection;


/**
 * Created by GIS on 28/09/2016.
 */

public class App extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier,RangeNotifier {
    private static final String TAG = "BeaconReferenceApp";
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
    private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
    private boolean haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = false;
    private MainActivity main=null;
    private BeaconManager mBeaconManager;


    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "DEFAULT", "fonts/ir.ttf");
        TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "MONOSPACE", "fonts/ir.ttf");
        TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "SERIF", "fonts/ir.ttf");
        TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "SANS_SERIF", "fonts/ir.ttf");

//        startService(new Intent(this, TestBestzBeaconService.class));


        mBeaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

        // By default the AndroidBeaconLibrary will only find AltBeacons.  If you wish to make it
        // find a different type of beacon, you must specify the byte layout for that beacon's
        // advertisement with a line like below.  The example shows how to find a beacon with the
        // same byte layout as AltBeacon but with a beaconTypeCode of 0xaabb.  To find the proper
        // layout expression for other beacon types, do a web search for "setBeaconLayout"
        // including the quotes.
        //
        //beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
        //beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
        //        setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));

        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=4c000215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("x,s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=20,d:3-3,d:4-5,d:6-7,d:8-11,d:12-15"));
        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19"));
        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=10,p:3-3:-41,i:4-20v"));
        mBeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=fed8,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-21v"));
        Log.d(TAG, "setting up background monitoring for beacons and power saving");
        // wake up the app when a beacon is seen
        Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion",
                null, null, null);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);

        // simply constructing this class and holding a reference to it in your custom Application
        // class will automatically cause the BeaconLibrary to save battery whenever the application
        // is not visible.  This reduces bluetooth power usage by about 60%
        backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);

        // If you wish to test beacon detection in the Android Emulator, you can use code like this:
        // BeaconManager.setBeaconSimulator(new TimedBeaconSimulator() );
   // ((TimedBeaconSimulator) BeaconManager.getBeaconSimulator()).createTimedSimulatedBeacons();

    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
        // In this example, this class sends a notification to the user whenever a Beacon
        // matching a Region (defined above) are first seen.
        try {
            mBeaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(arg0);
        }
        catch (RemoteException e) {
           Log.d(TAG, "Can't start ranging"+e.getMessage());
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "did enter region.");
        if (!haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "auto launching MainActivity");

            // The very first time since boot that we detect an beacon, we launch the
            // MainActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            // Important:  make sure to add android:launchMode="singleInstance" in the manifest
            // to keep multiple copies of this activity from getting created if the user has
            // already manually launched the app.
            this.startActivity(intent);
            haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = true;
        } else {
            if (main != null) {
                // If the Monitoring Activity is visible, we log info about the beacons we have
                // seen on its display
                Log.d(TAG, "I see a beacon again" );
            } else {
                // If we have already seen beacons before, but the monitoring activity is not in
                // the foreground, we send a notification to the user on subsequent detections.
                Log.d(TAG, "Sending notification.");
                sendNotification();
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {

            Log.d(TAG, "I no longer see a beacon.");

    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
        Log.d(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: " + state);
    }

    private void sendNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle("Beacon Reference Application")
                        .setContentText("An beacon is nearby.")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }

    public void setMonitoringActivity(MainActivity activity) {
        this.main = activity;
    }



    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
        Log.d(TAG, "didRangeBeaconsInRegion");
        if (beacons.size() > 0) {
            Beacon firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next();
             Log.d(TAG, "Beacon ranged: UUID: "
                    + firstBeacon.getId1().toString() + " Major: "
                    + firstBeacon.getId2().toString() + " Minor: "
                    + firstBeacon.getId3().toString());

            // Do something with the result

            // Stop ranging
            try {
                mBeaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

   // @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBeaconServiceConnect()");
    }
}
```

In above class `BootstrapNotifier` works fine. But `RangeNotifier` does not. `BootstrapNotifier` says that there is a beacon nearby but It does not give me list of beacons, So I have forced to use `RangeNotifier` but it does not work. Can you please help me find a solution for it?
thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the range notifier like this:

(If you have Library version 2.9+)

`beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(this);`

(If you have Library version pre-2.9)

`beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(this);`

Comment: Thanks very much,Do I need to create a service or an application class is enough and it scans for beacons in background

Comment: No need for a service -- the Android Beacon Library already has one that does the scanning in the background.  The Application class is a convenient mechanism in Android to link this service to your application code when scanning starts up.